# Dynamic Image in SSRS report Image control not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services

I have an Asp.net MVC 5 website that hosts a RDLC file.  I want to call a controller action to render an image in the report.  The Image control has "External" image source set.  I have tried passing the URL as a parameter to the report and setting the image expression to that parameter.  The image is blank.  The HTML in the browser states "src=unknown".  I have also tried hardcoding the expression.  No image displays.  When I put the URL in the browser, the image displays.  The hardcoded URL is ="http://localhost:55426/image/showbarcode?id=69899694-6ce4-e811-80cc-78e3b50d083e".  The website is not hosted in IIS.  No errors are reported

This is the only report that is using external images.  I did have to change the SSRS target server version to "SQL Server 2008 R2, 2012 or 2014".  All the other reports render fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My coworker changed the report to get the image from the database.  That fixed the problem.